# How to reduce the loading time of my sql query and minimize my code

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

How can i manage to minimize and optimize this mysql query, which is more faster and safer from bugs, please someone help me so i can configure my SQL query faster and efficient and also minimize the loading time of execution of mysql query. the main source of loading time is the join connection between attendance_03 and working_schedule_03 which partners each ids and date between two tables. kindly help me please, i really really need your help. here is my table columns

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT 
  `last_name`,
  `first_name`,
  `attendance_03`.`emp_id`,
  `departments`.`dept_name`,
  `departments`.`dept_id`,
  `employee_location`.`loc`,
  `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` AS mt_in,
  COUNT(attendance_03.a_id) AS Cymon 
FROM
  (`attendance_03`) 
  LEFT JOIN `working_schedule_03`  
    ON `working_schedule_03`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` AND CONCAT(`working_schedule_03`.`m`,`working_schedule_03`.`d`,`working_schedule_03`.`y`) = CONCAT(`attendance_03`.`mm`,`attendance_03`.`dd`,`attendance_03`.`yy`)
  LEFT JOIN `employee_personal_info` 
    ON `employee_personal_info`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_information` 
    ON `employee_information`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `departments` 
    ON `departments`.`dept_id` = `employee_information`.`department` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_location` 
    ON `employee_location`.`l_id` = `employee_information`.`loc` 
WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "07:00"
  AND 
    (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "07" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
      AND 59
    )
  AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
  AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
    AND 15) 
GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
UNION
SELECT 
  `last_name`,
  `first_name`,
  `attendance_03`.`emp_id`,
  `departments`.`dept_name`,
  `departments`.`dept_id`,
  `employee_location`.`loc`,
  `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` AS mt_in,
  COUNT(attendance_03.a_id) AS Cymon 
FROM
  (`attendance_03`) 
  LEFT JOIN `working_schedule_03`  
    ON `working_schedule_03`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` AND CONCAT(`working_schedule_03`.`m`,`working_schedule_03`.`d`,`working_schedule_03`.`y`) = CONCAT(`attendance_03`.`mm`,`attendance_03`.`dd`,`attendance_03`.`yy`)  
  LEFT JOIN `employee_personal_info` 
    ON `employee_personal_info`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_information` 
    ON `employee_information`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `departments` 
    ON `departments`.`dept_id` = `employee_information`.`department` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_location` 
    ON `employee_location`.`l_id` = `employee_information`.`loc` 
WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "07:30"
  AND (
    (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "07" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 31 
      AND 59
    ) 
    OR (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "08" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
      AND 30
    )
  ) 
  AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
  AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
    AND 15) 
GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
UNION
SELECT 
  `last_name`,
  `first_name`,
  `attendance_03`.`emp_id`,
  `departments`.`dept_name`,
  `departments`.`dept_id`,
  `employee_location`.`loc`,
  `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` AS mt_in,
  COUNT(attendance_03.a_id) AS Cymon 
FROM
  (`attendance_03`) 
  LEFT JOIN `working_schedule_03`  
    ON `working_schedule_03`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` AND CONCAT(`working_schedule_03`.`m`,`working_schedule_03`.`d`,`working_schedule_03`.`y`) = CONCAT(`attendance_03`.`mm`,`attendance_03`.`dd`,`attendance_03`.`yy`)  
  LEFT JOIN `employee_personal_info` 
    ON `employee_personal_info`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_information` 
    ON `employee_information`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `departments` 
    ON `departments`.`dept_id` = `employee_information`.`department` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_location` 
    ON `employee_location`.`l_id` = `employee_information`.`loc` 
WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "08:00"
  AND 
    (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "08" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
      AND 59
    )
  AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
  AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
    AND 15) 
GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
UNION
SELECT 
  `last_name`,
  `first_name`,
  `attendance_03`.`emp_id`,
  `departments`.`dept_name`,
  `departments`.`dept_id`,
  `employee_location`.`loc`,
  `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` AS mt_in,
  COUNT(attendance_03.a_id) AS Cymon 
FROM
  (`attendance_03`) 
  LEFT JOIN `working_schedule_03`  
    ON `working_schedule_03`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` AND CONCAT(`working_schedule_03`.`m`,`working_schedule_03`.`d`,`working_schedule_03`.`y`) = CONCAT(`attendance_03`.`mm`,`attendance_03`.`dd`,`attendance_03`.`yy`)  
  LEFT JOIN `employee_personal_info` 
    ON `employee_personal_info`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_information` 
    ON `employee_information`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `departments` 
    ON `departments`.`dept_id` = `employee_information`.`department` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_location` 
    ON `employee_location`.`l_id` = `employee_information`.`loc` 
WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "08:30"
  AND (
    (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "08" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 31 
      AND 59
    ) 
    OR (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "09" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
      AND 59
    )
  ) 
  AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
  AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
    AND 15) 
GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
UNION
SELECT 
  `last_name`,
  `first_name`,
  `attendance_03`.`emp_id`,
  `departments`.`dept_name`,
  `departments`.`dept_id`,
  `employee_location`.`loc`,
  `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` AS mt_in,
  COUNT(attendance_03.a_id) AS Cymon 
FROM
  (`attendance_03`) 
  LEFT JOIN `working_schedule_03`  
    ON `working_schedule_03`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` AND CONCAT(`working_schedule_03`.`m`,`working_schedule_03`.`d`,`working_schedule_03`.`y`) = CONCAT(`attendance_03`.`mm`,`attendance_03`.`dd`,`attendance_03`.`yy`)  
  LEFT JOIN `employee_personal_info` 
    ON `employee_personal_info`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_information` 
    ON `employee_information`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `departments` 
    ON `departments`.`dept_id` = `employee_information`.`department` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_location` 
    ON `employee_location`.`l_id` = `employee_information`.`loc` 
WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "09:00" 
  AND (
    HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "09" 
    AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
    AND 59
  ) 
  AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
  AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
    AND 15) 
GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
UNION
SELECT 
  `last_name`,
  `first_name`,
  `attendance_03`.`emp_id`,
  `departments`.`dept_name`,
  `departments`.`dept_id`,
  `employee_location`.`loc`,
  `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` AS mt_in,
  COUNT(attendance_03.a_id) AS Cymon 
FROM
  (`attendance_03`) 
  LEFT JOIN `working_schedule_03`  
    ON `working_schedule_03`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` AND CONCAT(`working_schedule_03`.`m`,`working_schedule_03`.`d`,`working_schedule_03`.`y`) = CONCAT(`attendance_03`.`mm`,`attendance_03`.`dd`,`attendance_03`.`yy`)  
  LEFT JOIN `employee_personal_info` 
    ON `employee_personal_info`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_information` 
    ON `employee_information`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `departments` 
    ON `departments`.`dept_id` = `employee_information`.`department` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_location` 
    ON `employee_location`.`l_id` = `employee_information`.`loc` 
WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "10:00"
  AND (
    HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "10" 
    AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
    AND 59
  ) 
  AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
  AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
    AND 15) 
GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
UNION
SELECT 
  `last_name`,
  `first_name`,
  `attendance_03`.`emp_id`,
  `departments`.`dept_name`,
  `departments`.`dept_id`,
  `employee_location`.`loc`,
  `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` AS mt_in,
  COUNT(attendance_03.a_id) AS Cymon 
FROM
  (`attendance_03`) 
  LEFT JOIN `working_schedule_03`  
    ON `working_schedule_03`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` AND CONCAT(`working_schedule_03`.`m`,`working_schedule_03`.`d`,`working_schedule_03`.`y`) = CONCAT(`attendance_03`.`mm`,`attendance_03`.`dd`,`attendance_03`.`yy`)  
  LEFT JOIN `employee_personal_info` 
    ON `employee_personal_info`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_information` 
    ON `employee_information`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `departments` 
    ON `departments`.`dept_id` = `employee_information`.`department` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_location` 
    ON `employee_location`.`l_id` = `employee_information`.`loc` 
WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "13:00"
  AND (
    HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "13" 
    AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
    AND 59
  ) 
  AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
  AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
    AND 15) 
GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
UNION
SELECT 
  `last_name`,
  `first_name`,
  `attendance_03`.`emp_id`,
  `departments`.`dept_name`,
  `departments`.`dept_id`,
  `employee_location`.`loc`,
  `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` AS mt_in,
  COUNT(attendance_03.a_id) AS Cymon 
FROM
  (`attendance_03`) 
  LEFT JOIN `working_schedule_03`  
    ON `working_schedule_03`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` AND CONCAT(`working_schedule_03`.`m`,`working_schedule_03`.`d`,`working_schedule_03`.`y`) = CONCAT(`attendance_03`.`mm`,`attendance_03`.`dd`,`attendance_03`.`yy`)  
  LEFT JOIN `employee_personal_info` 
    ON `employee_personal_info`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_information` 
    ON `employee_information`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `departments` 
    ON `departments`.`dept_id` = `employee_information`.`department` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_location` 
    ON `employee_location`.`l_id` = `employee_information`.`loc` 
WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "15:00"
  AND (
    HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "15" 
    AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
    AND 59
  ) 
  AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
  AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
    AND 15) 
GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
UNION
SELECT 
  `last_name`,
  `first_name`,
  `attendance_03`.`emp_id`,
  `departments`.`dept_name`,
  `departments`.`dept_id`,
  `employee_location`.`loc`,
  `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` AS mt_in,
  COUNT(attendance_03.a_id) AS Cymon 
FROM
  (`attendance_03`) 
  LEFT JOIN `working_schedule_03`  
    ON `working_schedule_03`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` AND CONCAT(`working_schedule_03`.`m`,`working_schedule_03`.`d`,`working_schedule_03`.`y`) = CONCAT(`attendance_03`.`mm`,`attendance_03`.`dd`,`attendance_03`.`yy`)  
  LEFT JOIN `employee_personal_info` 
    ON `employee_personal_info`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_information` 
    ON `employee_information`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `departments` 
    ON `departments`.`dept_id` = `employee_information`.`department` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_location` 
    ON `employee_location`.`l_id` = `employee_information`.`loc` 
WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "16:00"
  AND (
    HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "16" 
    AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
    AND 59
  ) 
  AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
  AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
    AND 15) 
GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
UNION
SELECT 
  `last_name`,
  `first_name`,
  `attendance_03`.`emp_id`,
  `departments`.`dept_name`,
  `departments`.`dept_id`,
  `employee_location`.`loc`,
  `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` AS mt_in,
  COUNT(attendance_03.a_id) AS Cymon 
FROM
  (`attendance_03`) 
  LEFT JOIN `working_schedule_03`  
    ON `working_schedule_03`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` AND CONCAT(`working_schedule_03`.`m`,`working_schedule_03`.`d`,`working_schedule_03`.`y`) = CONCAT(`attendance_03`.`mm`,`attendance_03`.`dd`,`attendance_03`.`yy`)  
  LEFT JOIN `employee_personal_info` 
    ON `employee_personal_info`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_information` 
    ON `employee_information`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `departments` 
    ON `departments`.`dept_id` = `employee_information`.`department` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_location` 
    ON `employee_location`.`l_id` = `employee_information`.`loc` 
WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "17:00"
  AND (
    HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "17" 
    AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
    AND 59
  ) 
  AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
  AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
    AND 15) 
GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
UNION
SELECT 
  `last_name`,
  `first_name`,
  `attendance_03`.`emp_id`,
  `departments`.`dept_name`,
  `departments`.`dept_id`,
  `employee_location`.`loc`,
  `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` AS mt_in,
  COUNT(attendance_03.a_id) AS Cymon 
FROM
  (`attendance_03`) 
  LEFT JOIN `working_schedule_03`  
    ON `working_schedule_03`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` AND CONCAT(`working_schedule_03`.`m`,`working_schedule_03`.`d`,`working_schedule_03`.`y`) = CONCAT(`attendance_03`.`mm`,`attendance_03`.`dd`,`attendance_03`.`yy`)  
  LEFT JOIN `employee_personal_info` 
    ON `employee_personal_info`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_information` 
    ON `employee_information`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `departments` 
    ON `departments`.`dept_id` = `employee_information`.`department` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_location` 
    ON `employee_location`.`l_id` = `employee_information`.`loc` 
WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "19:00"
  AND (
    HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "19" 
    AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
    AND 59
  ) 
  AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
  AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
    AND 15) 
GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
UNION
SELECT 
  `last_name`,
  `first_name`,
  `attendance_03`.`emp_id`,
  `departments`.`dept_name`,
  `departments`.`dept_id`,
  `employee_location`.`loc`,
  `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` AS mt_in,
  COUNT(attendance_03.a_id) AS Cymon 
FROM
  (`attendance_03`) 
  LEFT JOIN `working_schedule_03`  
    ON `working_schedule_03`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` AND CONCAT(`working_schedule_03`.`m`,`working_schedule_03`.`d`,`working_schedule_03`.`y`) = CONCAT(`attendance_03`.`mm`,`attendance_03`.`dd`,`attendance_03`.`yy`)  
  LEFT JOIN `employee_personal_info` 
    ON `employee_personal_info`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_information` 
    ON `employee_information`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `departments` 
    ON `departments`.`dept_id` = `employee_information`.`department` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_location` 
    ON `employee_location`.`l_id` = `employee_information`.`loc` 
WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "19:30"
  AND (
    (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "19" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 31 
      AND 59
    ) 
    OR (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "20" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
      AND 30
    )
  ) 
  AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
  AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
    AND 15) 
GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
UNION
SELECT 
  `last_name`,
  `first_name`,
  `attendance_03`.`emp_id`,
  `departments`.`dept_name`,
  `departments`.`dept_id`,
  `employee_location`.`loc`,
  `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` AS mt_in,
  COUNT(attendance_03.a_id) AS Cymon 
FROM
  (`attendance_03`) 
  LEFT JOIN `working_schedule_03`  
    ON `working_schedule_03`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` AND CONCAT(`working_schedule_03`.`m`,`working_schedule_03`.`d`,`working_schedule_03`.`y`) = CONCAT(`attendance_03`.`mm`,`attendance_03`.`dd`,`attendance_03`.`yy`)  
  LEFT JOIN `employee_personal_info` 
    ON `employee_personal_info`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_information` 
    ON `employee_information`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `departments` 
    ON `departments`.`dept_id` = `employee_information`.`department` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_location` 
    ON `employee_location`.`l_id` = `employee_information`.`loc` 
WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "20:00"
  AND (
    HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "20" 
    AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
    AND 59
  ) 
  AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
  AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
    AND 15) 
GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
UNION
SELECT 
  `last_name`,
  `first_name`,
  `attendance_03`.`emp_id`,
  `departments`.`dept_name`,
  `departments`.`dept_id`,
  `employee_location`.`loc`,
  `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` AS mt_in,
  COUNT(attendance_03.a_id) AS Cymon 
FROM
  (`attendance_03`) 
  LEFT JOIN `working_schedule_03`  
    ON `working_schedule_03`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` AND CONCAT(`working_schedule_03`.`m`,`working_schedule_03`.`d`,`working_schedule_03`.`y`) = CONCAT(`attendance_03`.`mm`,`attendance_03`.`dd`,`attendance_03`.`yy`)  
  LEFT JOIN `employee_personal_info` 
    ON `employee_personal_info`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_information` 
    ON `employee_information`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `departments` 
    ON `departments`.`dept_id` = `employee_information`.`department` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_location` 
    ON `employee_location`.`l_id` = `employee_information`.`loc` 
WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "21:00"
  AND (
    HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "21" 
    AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
    AND 59
  ) 
  AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
  AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
    AND 15) 
GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
UNION
SELECT 
  `last_name`,
  `first_name`,
  `attendance_03`.`emp_id`,
  `departments`.`dept_name`,
  `departments`.`dept_id`,
  `employee_location`.`loc`,
  `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` AS mt_in,
  COUNT(attendance_03.a_id) AS Cymon 
FROM
  (`attendance_03`) 
  LEFT JOIN `working_schedule_03`  
    ON `working_schedule_03`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` AND CONCAT(`working_schedule_03`.`m`,`working_schedule_03`.`d`,`working_schedule_03`.`y`) = CONCAT(`attendance_03`.`mm`,`attendance_03`.`dd`,`attendance_03`.`yy`)  
  LEFT JOIN `employee_personal_info` 
    ON `employee_personal_info`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_information` 
    ON `employee_information`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `departments` 
    ON `departments`.`dept_id` = `employee_information`.`department` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_location` 
    ON `employee_location`.`l_id` = `employee_information`.`loc` 
WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "23:45"
  AND (
    (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "23" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 46 
      AND 59
    ) 
    OR (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "24" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
      AND 45
    )
  ) 
  AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
  AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
    AND 15) 
GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1) AS g 
ORDER BY g.loc,
g.dept_id,
g.last_name ASC
```

Here is my Table attendance_03

```
CREATE TABLE `attendance_03` (
  `a_id` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_in` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_b1_out` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_b1_in` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_lb_out` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_lb_in` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_b2_out` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_b2_in` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_out` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `mu` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `mm` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `dd` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `yy` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `d_out` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `d_b1_out` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `d_b1_in` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `d_lb_out` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `d_lb_in` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `d_b2_out` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `d_b2_in` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `emp_id` varchar(99) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here is my working_schedule_03 table

```
CREATE TABLE `working_schedule_03` (
  `id` mediumint(99) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `m` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `d` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `y` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `emp_id` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `eve` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_in` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_out` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `emp_file` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `dt_plot` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=572136 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: um wow - i think we nneed to see data and the db schema. i'm kind of sure you don't need all those unions

Comment: no index but the key- well ethers a good start

Comment: attendance_03 column t_in have different type of value in my working_schedule_03 which the scheduled date of the employee for example his schedule date is 8:00 then my attendance_03 t_in will check if there are late in 8:00 working_schedule, note that attendance_03 values is the actual time in of the employee

Comment: Hi Mr. Dragon do you have solutionfor this? its working but i really wanted is shortened my sql query and reduce the execution time which is loads more than 4 mins

Comment: have you added indexes on these tables?

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* split DATE into yy, mm, dd.  Do *not* use VARCHAR for numeric values.  Ditto for time components.

Pull all the identical JOINs outside the UNION.

Index the field(s) you are JOINing on.

Don't use `LEFT` unless the 'right' table might have missing rows.

Fix those, Then come back for another thrashing.

Comment: Hi Rick James, its an exisiting database of the company and i can't changed it because it is being used by our hris. i'm just modifying the system and adding some module for sms and email notifications of employee with late frequency greater than 1. thanks!

Comment: i remove all the joins and select columns that is identical and put it on the outside of the union then i add WHERE from the first union which is (Select, then i have an error my friend. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: but it has an error: operand should contain 1 column(s)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the optimize sql query i made.

```
SELECT 
  `last_name`,
  `first_name`,
  `attendance_03`.`emp_id`,
  `departments`.`dept_name`,
  `departments`.`dept_id`,
  `employee_location`.`loc`,
  `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` AS mt_in,
  COUNT(attendance_03.a_id) AS Cymon 
FROM
  (`attendance_03`) 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      * 
    FROM
      `working_schedule_03` 
    WHERE `eve` = "Regular" 
      AND `y` = 2015 
    GROUP BY `emp_id`) AS `working_schedule_03` 
    ON `working_schedule_03`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_personal_info` 
    ON `employee_personal_info`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_information` 
    ON `employee_information`.`emp_id` = `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `departments` 
    ON `departments`.`dept_id` = `employee_information`.`department` 
  LEFT JOIN `employee_location` 
    ON `employee_location`.`l_id` = `employee_information`.`loc` 
WHERE 
  (SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
    (`attendance_03`) 
  WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "07:00" 
    AND (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "07" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
      AND 59
    ) 
    AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
    AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
      AND 15) 
    AND `employee_location`.`l_id` = 2 
  GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
    (`attendance_03`) 
  WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "07:30" 
    AND (
      (
        HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "07" 
        AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 31 
        AND 59
      ) 
      OR (
        HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "08" 
        AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
        AND 30
      )
    ) 
    AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
    AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
      AND 15) 
    AND `employee_location`.`l_id` = 2 
  GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
    (`attendance_03`) 
  WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "08:00" 
    AND (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "08" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
      AND 59
    ) 
    AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
    AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
      AND 15) 
    AND `employee_location`.`l_id` = 2 
  GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
    (`attendance_03`) 
  WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "08:30" 
    AND (
      (
        HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "08" 
        AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 31 
        AND 59
      ) 
      OR (
        HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "09" 
        AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
        AND 59
      )
    ) 
    AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
    AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
      AND 15) 
    AND `employee_location`.`l_id` = 2 
  GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
    (`attendance_03`) 
  WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "09:00" 
    AND (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "09" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
      AND 59
    ) 
    AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
    AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
      AND 15) 
    AND `employee_location`.`l_id` = 2 
  GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
    (`attendance_03`) 
  WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "10:00" 
    AND (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "10" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
      AND 59
    ) 
    AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
    AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
      AND 15) 
    AND `employee_location`.`l_id` = 2 
  GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
    (`attendance_03`) 
  WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "13:00" 
    AND (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "13" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
      AND 59
    ) 
    AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
    AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
      AND 15) 
    AND `employee_location`.`l_id` = 2 
  GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
    (`attendance_03`) 
  WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "15:00" 
    AND (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "15" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
      AND 59
    ) 
    AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
    AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
      AND 15) 
    AND `employee_location`.`l_id` = 2 
  GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
    (`attendance_03`) 
  WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "16:00" 
    AND (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "16" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
      AND 59
    ) 
    AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
    AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
      AND 15) 
    AND `employee_location`.`l_id` = 2 
  GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
    (`attendance_03`) 
  WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "17:00" 
    AND (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "17" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
      AND 59
    ) 
    AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
    AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
      AND 15) 
    AND `employee_location`.`l_id` = 2 
  GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
    (`attendance_03`) 
  WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "19:00" 
    AND (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "19" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
      AND 59
    ) 
    AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
    AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
      AND 15) 
    AND `employee_location`.`l_id` = 2 
  GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
    (`attendance_03`) 
  WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "19:30" 
    AND (
      (
        HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "19" 
        AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 31 
        AND 59
      ) 
      OR (
        HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "20" 
        AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
        AND 30
      )
    ) 
    AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
    AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
      AND 15) 
    AND `employee_location`.`l_id` = 2 
  GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
    (`attendance_03`) 
  WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "20:00" 
    AND (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "20" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
      AND 59
    ) 
    AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
    AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
      AND 15) 
    AND `employee_location`.`l_id` = 2 
  GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
    (`attendance_03`) 
  WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "21:00" 
    AND (
      HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "21" 
      AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
      AND 59
    ) 
    AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
    AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
      AND 15) 
    AND `employee_location`.`l_id` = 2 
  GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
    (`attendance_03`) 
  WHERE `working_schedule_03`.`t_in` = "23:45" 
    AND (
      (
        HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "23" 
        AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 46 
        AND 59
      ) 
      OR (
        HOUR(attendance_03.t_in) = "24" 
        AND MINUTE(attendance_03.t_in) BETWEEN 01 
        AND 45
      )
    ) 
    AND attendance_03.yy = 2015 
    AND (attendance_03.dd BETWEEN 01 
      AND 15) 
    AND `employee_location`.`l_id` = 2 
  GROUP BY `attendance_03`.`emp_id` 
  HAVING COUNT(attendance_03.emp_id) > 1)
```

Comment: convert dd, mm, yy columns to single date column and then use mysql date function in where and join clauses, moreover with this your query will be automatically shortened. So the basic problem i found in your query is just because your db structure is not good

Comment: yes imran, i'm the one who maintains this db right now, so i'm the one having burden because of developer who ditch my company, but if you can help me to minimize my code, you'll surely be my sweetest escape from my darkest hours

Comment: yes i can do this for you, you can contact me on skype, further we can discuss there, find my skype id from my profile

Comment: i will Imran, but for now there are some things i need to accomplish first, will just add you on skype. thanks!